# How to have pandas perform a rolling average on a non-uniform x-grid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I would like to perform a rolling average but with a window that only has a finite 'vision' in x. I would like something similar to what I have below, but I want a window range that based on the x value rather than position index.

While doing this within pandas is preferred numpy/scipy equivalents are also OK

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

x_val = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
y_val = [x+np.random.random()*200 for x in x_val]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x_val,'y':y_val})
df.set_index('x', inplace=True)

df.plot()
df.rolling(1, win_type='gaussian').mean(std=2).plot()
```

So I would expect the first 5 values to be averaged together because they are within 10 xunits of each other, but the last values to be unchanged.

Comment: An option might be to create an additional (filtered) column containing only the values within a defined range (e.g. <=10); then perform the rolling mean on that column.

Comment: What can you guarantee about the x values? Are they guaranteed to be strictly increasing? Or is it possible to have a sequence of x like [1,2,4,3]?

Comment: If it helps we can guarantee that x is strictly increasing (can always sort x & y to ensure this).

Comment: Could you add a dummy example of an input and expected output as well? I am a bit confused about the part where you mentioned `but I want only values within a certain range (e.g. only values within a range of 10).` What is the 10 here? Is that a window size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `pandas` [documentation on `rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

> Size of the moving window. This is the number of observations used for calculating the statistic. Each window will be a fixed size.

Therefore, maybe you need to fake a rolling operation with various window sizes like this

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.linspace(1,10,10),'y':np.linspace(1,10,10)})
test_df['win_locs'] = np.linspace(1,10,10).astype('object')
for ind in range(10): test_df.at[ind,'win_locs'] = np.random.randint(0,10,np.random.randint(5)).tolist()

    
# rolling operation with various window sizes
def worker(idx_list):
    
    x_slice = test_df.loc[idx_list,'x']
    return np.sum(x_slice)

test_df['rolling'] = test_df['win_locs'].apply(worker)
```

As you can see, `test_df` is

```
      x     y      win_locs  rolling
0   1.0   1.0        [5, 2]      9.0
1   2.0   2.0  [4, 8, 7, 1]     24.0
2   3.0   3.0            []      0.0
3   4.0   4.0           [9]     10.0
4   5.0   5.0     [6, 2, 9]     20.0
5   6.0   6.0            []      0.0
6   7.0   7.0     [5, 7, 9]     24.0
7   8.0   8.0            []      0.0
8   9.0   9.0            []      0.0
9  10.0  10.0  [9, 4, 7, 1]     25.0
```

where the rolling operation is achieved with `apply` method.

**However, this approach is significantly slower than the native `rolling`**, for example,

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.linspace(1,10,10),'y':np.linspace(1,10,10)})
test_df['win_locs'] = np.linspace(1,10,10).astype('object')
for ind in range(10): test_df.at[ind,'win_locs'] = np.arange(ind-1,ind+1).tolist() if ind >= 1 else []
```

using the approach above

```
%%timeit
# rolling operation with various window sizes
def worker(idx_list):
    
    x_slice = test_df.loc[idx_list,'x']
    return np.sum(x_slice)

test_df['rolling_apply'] = test_df['win_locs'].apply(worker)
```

the result is

```
41.4 ms ± 4.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

while using native `rolling` is ~x50 faster

```
%%timeit
test_df['rolling_native'] = test_df['x'].rolling(window=2).sum()

863 µs ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

The key question remains: what do you want to achieve with the rolling mean ?

Mathematically a clean way is:

1. interpolate to the finest dx of the x-data
2. perform the rolling mean
3. take out the data points you want (But be careful: this step is a type of averaging too!)

Here is the code for the interpolation:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x_val = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
y_val = [x+np.random.random()*200 for x in x_val]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x_val,'y':y_val})
df.set_index('x', inplace=True)

#df.plot()
df.rolling(5, win_type='gaussian').mean(std=200).plot()


#---- Interpolation -----------------------------------
f1 = interp1d(x_val, y_val)
f2 = interp1d(x_val, y_val, kind='cubic')

dx = np.diff(x_val).min()  # get the smallest dx in the x-data set

xnew = np.arange(x_val[0], x_val[-1]+dx, step=dx)
ynew1 = f1(xnew)
ynew2 = f2(xnew)

#---- plot ---------------------------------------------
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(x_val, y_val, '-o', label='data', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xnew, ynew1, '|', ms = 15, c='r', label='linear', zorder=1)
#plt.plot(xnew, ynew2, label='cubic')
plt.savefig('curve.png')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, someone will come with a faster solution.
Meanwhile, you can use the `DataFrame.iterrows()` for doing that:

```py
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx, 'avg'] = df.loc[idx-10:idx, 'y'].mean()
```

Output:

```
              y         avg
x                          
1     26.540168   26.540168
2     28.255431   27.397799
4    114.941475   56.579025
8    156.347716   81.521197
16   168.563203  162.455459
32    36.054945   36.054945
64   179.384703  179.384703
128  225.098994  225.098994
256  340.718363  340.718363
512  551.927011  551.927011
```